# inserting a book but have a many author php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem with inserting the data of book when the book have many author how to insert it in my database without reduntant of data and this is my code for getting the info of the author but how can i insert it in one row? or any solution to my problem thanks

```
<input type="text" required  name="author[]" placeholder="Author" class="form-control name_list" />
<button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=1;  
  var maxfield = 2;
  $('#add').click(function(){
  if (i < maxfield) {
          i++;  
       $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="author[]" required  placehold="Author" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  


  }  
   });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
       i--;  
  });  
  $('#submit').click(function(){            
       $.ajax({  
            url:"addingbook.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
            success:function(data)  

            { 

                 alert(data);  
                 $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                 window.location.href = 'book.php';
            }  
       });  
  });  


});
```

```
$number = count($_POST["author"]);
if($number > 0)  
}
    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
  {  
       if(trim($_POST["author"][$i] != ''))  
       {  
$sql = "INSERT INTO book(title, author, publisher, publishdate)VALUES('$title', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["author"][$i])."', '$publisher', , '$publishdate')";  
         $insert =   mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 

}}}
```

Comment: unclear what your issue is.... You say how to get it into the database, but I see no database code in your question.

Comment: im already have a code wait let me edit my post

Comment: *"but how can i insert it in one row?"* - I'd argue that you probably shouldn't - one book with many authors, so the authors should be added to an *author* table and just connected to the book with a link table.

Comment: the author table have a column of title and author then join the table book and author? is that it?

Comment: Not quite, you have a table for `author` (which holds information about the author; name, bio whatever) and another table that *links* books to authors; at it's most basic that's just a table with 2 columns, `book_id` and `author_id` (which make a compound primary key)... that way you can have one book with many authors **and** one author who's written many books.